# Rotating a 3D matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3D matrix with the dimensions 6, 2, and 10. I want the row dimension to switch places with the height dimension, that is, 10-2-6. [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html) doesn't achieve this the way I want.

How can this be done? Can I rotate the matrix?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/permute.html). For your case it's, `permute(A,[3 2 1]);`. Here's a description of `permute` from the documentation:

> `B = permute(A,order)` rearranges the
>   dimensions of A so that they are in
>   the order specified by the vector
>   order. B has the same values of A but
>   the order of the subscripts needed to
>   access any particular element is
>   rearranged as specified by order. All
>   the elements of order must be unique.the elements of order must be unique.

It's similar to transposing a 2D matrix.